# Mocking Files.copy in spring boot unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to mock the following function in a unit test case:

```
Files.copy(response.getBody(), pathObj, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

`StandardCopyOption` is an enum of `java.nio.file` package:

The way I am trying to mock is:

```
    try {
        Mockito.doNothing().when(Files.copy(Mockito.any(InputStream.class), Mockito.any(Path.class), Mockito.any(CopyOption.class)));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
-> at scheduler.DownloadTest.downloadFile(DownloadTest.java:227)
-> at scheduler.DownloadTest.downloadFile(DownloadTest.java:227)
-> at scheduler.DownloadTest.downloadFile(DownloadTest.java:227)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Comment: Could you use an in-memory filesystem instead? https://github.com/google/jimfs

Comment: mdewit is fully correct; you can't use Mockito to mock static methods (maybe you want to spend some time reading the Mockito documentation; such things are clearly stated there). So, the only two options are: make your un-testable design testable; by following that answer; or turn to PowerMock(ito). I strongly recommend to go for the first option.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to mock a static method. Mockito does not allow this. You can only provide behavior for a non-static method of an actual mocked class instance.

When you use

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(Files.copy(Mockito.any(InputStream.class), Mockito.any(Path.class), Mockito.any(CopyOption.class)));
```

In the when() method, mockito expects the reference to the class that you are trying to mock. Then afterwards, you need to specify the method with its parameters.

Eg:

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(classInstance).copy(...)
```

However, since copy in this case is a static method, the above will not work (in your code you provide the return value of Files.copy as the class reference). So one solution will be to either use PowerMock (which can mock static methods but is not compatible with the later versions of mockito) or wrap the Files class in an instance wrapper.

Eg:

```
class FilesWrapper {
   public long copy(InputStream in, Path target, CopyOption... options) {
      return Files.copy(in, target, options);
   }
}
```

Now, inject a mocked FilesWrapper instance (Mockito.mock(FilesWrapper.class)) into your code and use it wherever you use Files.copy. Since the default behaviour of mockito is to do nothing for methods of mocked class instances, you only need to create the mock.

Another alternative would be to move the Files.copy part into a protected method of the class under test. This protected method can then be overridden during the test.